# How can I load external Jar in Android?

Tags: android, reflection

Im using Reflection in Android and I need to read a method inside a external jar file. Is a Java jar. Can I do it? Im just get read the jar if a have the jar inside my project but I need to read it out of my project, just loading it. Can anybody help me?

Comment: What? Can you please be more clear?

Comment: I need to load a jar save in my Android device and read it! I need to use a method from jar in Reflection.

Comment: In general, while accessing any external file, you must write the code within try block to catch FileNotFoundException. And if the method in your JAR file  has public methods, then you can access it by storing it into Apps dedicated storage.

Comment: Have a look at this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60764/how-should-i-load-jars-dynamically-at-runtime